# Stripes @SessionScope hides Stripes:errors

Tags: java, stripes, session-scope

I need to use @SessionScope to make a list stay in the page after refreshing, but when I use it, Stripes:error is not diplaying any more. Stripes:error runs actually(as I see nothing will happen) but it just doesn't show the error message in the page any more. I'm sure there is something with @SessionScope because when I run the code without it all the errors shown in the page.
Any Idea of how to fix this?

Note: I also tried to use @Wizard(startEvents="event") and it lets errors to be shown but doesn't do anything with saving the list in the page!

java

```
@SessionScope
@UrlBinding("/Student/import.action")
public class ImportAction implements ActionBean {
    private String userCheckBox;
    public Resolution importStudents() throws IOException {
      if (userCheckBox == null) {
                      this.getContext().getValidationErrors().add("userCheckBox",new SimpleError(error));
            }
    return new RedirectResolution("import.action");
}
public String getUserCheckBox() {
    return userCheckBox;
}
public void setUserCheckBox(String userCheckBox) {
    this.userCheckBox = userCheckBox;
}
}
```

jsp

```
<stripes:checkbox name="userCheckBox"/>
<stripes:errors field="userCheckBox"/>
<stripes:submit name="importStudents" value="Import"/>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using @Validate on the userCheckBox so that you don't have to do that manual error checking?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the correct way to do this but instead of using @SessionScope how about storing the list in the session directly via your subclassed ActionBeanContext?  For example, mine has

```
public class IlmpActionBeanContext extends ActionBeanContext {
private static final String REQUEST_TOKEN = "request_token";

public Token getRequestToken() {
    return (Token) this.getRequest().getSession()
        .getAttribute(IlmpActionBeanContext.REQUEST_TOKEN);
}

public void setRequestToken(final Token requestToken) {
    this.getRequest()
    .getSession()
    .setAttribute(IlmpActionBeanContext.REQUEST_TOKEN, requestToken);
}
```